# Jasperreport fit paper size B5

Tags: jasper-reports, page-size

I have a jasper report template, the page size is A4, and now want to print it on B5 paper. What can I do to make the content not print out of the paper.

Answer (score 4):

If you use TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio you can do this :

1. Open the report.
2. Right click inside the report :

[image: Screenshot]

3. Set page format to B5 :

[image: Format]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `pageWidth="501"` and `pageHeight="709"` on `jasperReport` tag

[ISO 216](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216), as you can see the B5 is 176 × 250 in mm

In jasper report size is indicated in pixel (DPI 72)

```
pixels = (mm * dpi) / 25.4; //The DPI in jasper report is 72
```

*The calculation will give width 499, jasper report uses as default 501, considering that the format has a 1,5 mm tolerance, either value will be fine.*

**Example with margin 20**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testSize" pageWidth="501" pageHeight="709" columnWidth="461" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e1be95c1-b1c3-499e-b902-99cda67676af">
```